# Perl Net::SSH2 hangs at channel()

Tags: perl, ssh

I'm creating a Perl script to send commands to a system using SSH2. It's not a standard Linux shell, but instead it's a proprietary shell. It does not accept commands through the SSH command (user@192.168.1.2 command) but it needs to connect first and then give commands to it like a shell.

I've came up with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::SSH2;

my $host = "192.168.1.2";
my $user = "admin";
my $password = "";

#-- set up a new connection
my $ssh = Net::SSH2->new();
$ssh->connect($host);

#-- authenticate
$ssh->auth_password($user, $password);

#-- creating a channel
my $channel = $ssh->channel();

#-- running a command
$channel->exec("xstatus");

#-- Closing the connection
$channel->close;
$ssh->disconnect;
```

The problem however is that it hangs at the '$ssh->channel()' line. There's a waiting prompt that doesn't go away. I've tried to remove all lines below it, but the issue remains. When I remove the 'channel()' line, it launches instantly. Is this a bug in the Net::SSH2 module, or am I doing something terribly wrong?

Comment: Well, you could try checking the return value of `auth_password` to see if it actually authenticated...

Comment: also try $ssh->auth_keyboard($user, $password) or die "can't connect $@";

Comment: it may be a bug on Net::SSH2. Even if `connect` or `auth_password` had failed it shouldn't block forever at `channel`.

Answer (score 0):

Per @user1269955: I figured it out. Had to replace 'auth_password' with 'auth_keyboard' for keyboard-interactive logon.